# How can I get Access Token through FBConnect API?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to know if I can get an Access Token through the FBConnect API, using the iPhone SDK.

I can get one through FBGraph, but I want to use FBConnect.

I also want to know if I can integrate FBGraph and FBConnect both into one iPhone application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out documentation for facebook-ios-sdk on github. Also you mixed your question with a lot of buzzwords, it is a bit unclear what exactly you are going to ask. Please rephrase your question if the mentioned sdk and documentation does not help.